# What is the relationship between flame graph and ebpf？

Tags: linux, performance, ebpf, flamegraph

flame graph based on ebpf ?
What is the relationship between flame graph and ebpf ？

Answer (score 1):

You **don't need eBPF to draw CPU flame graphs**. You can just [use perf to collect the appropriate data](https://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpuflamegraphs.html#perf).

So in short, eBPF and perf are two different ways, among others, to collect data to draw a flame graph from. See https://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpuflamegraphs.html#Instructions for examples on CPU flame graphs.